# Drupal 8, get programmatically the list of fields of a custom content

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-nodes, drupal-fields

I want create programmatically a custom content (custom content created via the admin UI). But, before the creation, I want check programmatically the types of fields of my custom content

My custom content contains a field "body" (type text), a field "description" (type text), an int field (type int), an attached file field (type fid ?)...

I test several ways with the new api of Drupal 8, my last try..

```
// I get the entity object "my_custom_content"
$entity_object = NodeType::load("my_custom_content");
dpm($entity_object); //Work perfectly


$test = \Drupal::getContainer()->get("entity_field.manager")->getFieldDefinitions("my_custom_content",$entity_object->bundle())
//The \Drupal::getConta... Return an error : The "my_custom_content" entity type does not exist.
```

With this $entity_object, how can I get the list of the fields of my custom content ? 
I see the EntityFieldManager Class, the FieldItemList Class...But I still do not understand how to play with drupal 8 / class / poo ... :/

Thanks !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NodeType is the (config) bundle entity for the Node (content) entity.

The correct call would be:

```
\Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'my_custom_content');
```

To get the field definitions of any entity_type use the following structure:

```
\Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions(ENTITY_TYPE_ID, BUNDLE_ID);
```

For example, if you want to get all the field definitions of a paragraph bundle with the id multy_purpose_link then replace ENTITY_TYPE_ID with paragraph and BUNDLE_ID with multy_purpose_link

```
\Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('paragraph', 'multy_purpose_link');
```

Comment: Working fine with node content type, but not work with "Paragarph" entity type.

Comment: $fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('paragraphs_type', 'paragraphs_name');

Comment: Updated the answer with a more general explanation.

Comment: To get the field names, you can use `array_keys()` on a result from this answer, e.g. `$fieldNames = array_keys($fieldDefinitions);`.

Answer (score 3):

The given answers are deprecated. You should now load the entity and just use `getFieldDefinitions()` to fetch the field definitions.

```
$node = Node::load($slide_id);
$field_defs = $node->getFieldDefinitions();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
$field_defs = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('taxonomy_term', '<taxonomy machine name here>');
```

If you want to get the list of field_definitions for a taxonomy vocabulary

Answer (score 1):

If the entity type does not have a bundle, for example the user entity.

Try this:

```
 // All user fields and ones added 
 $user_fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('user','user'); 

// Just default 
$default_user_fields  = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('user', NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks @Taggart Jensen. I was searching the bundle to use for custom user fields. This was the perfect answer.